# How to send an Image from Mongo DB to Ext JS with an Java Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, extjs, extjs4

I have an Java Servlet which tries to send an Image from Mongo DB to Ext JS:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String action = req.getParameter("action");

    if (action != null && action.equals("download")) {

        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + "images.jpg");

        try {
            DB db = DataBaseMongoService.getDb("forum_images"); //class that manages Mongo DB access
            GridFS gfs = new GridFS(db, "image");
            GridFSDBFile imageForOutput = gfs.findOne("images.jpg");

            InputStream in = imageForOutput.getInputStream();

            ServletOutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();
            out.write(IOUtils.toByteArray(in));
            out.flush();
            in.close();
            out.close();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My Ext JS call looks like this:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
url: 'ForumImageServlet',
method: 'GET',
params: {
    action: 'download'
},});
```

The Response is the bytestream of the image that looks like this:

```
ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½JFIFï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ "" $(4,$&1'-=-157:::#+?D?8C49:77%w777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777ï¿½ï¿½Pp"ï¿½ï¿½ï...
```

How can I get a real image as a response to my servlet?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rather than sending the image, could you send your image url ? Will be much easier to handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution was encoding the bytestream to base64:

```
            byte[] buf = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);

        String prefix = "{\"url\":\"data:image/jpeg;base64,";
        String postfix = "\"}";
        String fileJson = prefix + Base64.encodeBytes(buf).replaceAll("\n", "") + postfix; 
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.write(fileJson);
        out.flush();
        in.close();
        out.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you set `ContentType` to `text/html`?

Try using `image/jpg`

Comment: doesn't work, i think the extjs framework can only read text/html

Answer (score 0):

instead of using ajax requests, you can inject an img-tag with src attribute. when you provide the correct mime-type, your browser loads the image